# Python code stops after opening visual studio and doesn't execute the next line

Tags: python, os.system

I am using python to automate two simple processes: 
1. Open visual studio where my C code is located
2. press F5 button when visual studio is opened to run the visual studio code.

I am successfully able to open visual studio but not able to press the F5 button because the python code is stopped right there and won't continue to the next line. I verified this by putting a print statement.

Here is the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import os

os.system("C:/Users/Kailash/Dropbox/Visual_Studio_2013/Projects/Pedometer/Pedometer/Pedometer.vcxproj")

print ("hello")

time.sleep(15)

pyautogui.press('f5')
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function `os.system()` will not return unil the requested progam terminates - that is, until you close VS.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now, when the VS is open, I need to press F5 key which makes the VS run.. How do I do that? @DYZ

Comment: You need to start a separate thread that will execute the rest of your program.

Comment: I used subprocess and tried to execute the rest of the program and it does execute but the F5 function key does NOT make the VS run, meaning, the F5 key is not being performed on the VS which is opened by the same script.

Comment: The VS window must receive focus first. You can read more about focusing here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/. I have never used it, so I cannot be of any further help.

Comment: As an alternative to pressing `F5`, you could pass [`/Command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sf6kk3.aspx) on the command line to `devenv.exe` to get it to execute any command you want after loading.